# find matches after lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

**EDIT #1:** Fixed the JSON

**EDIT #2:** I'm aware of the option to use json, but I need to use regex to solve this issue.

I'm trying to find all IP ranges (CIDRs) pattens after a particular patter. For example, for the given input:

```
{"ips":{"ingress":{"all":["104.16.51.111/32","104.16.53.111/32"],"specific":["104.16.51.111/32","104.16.53.111/32"]},"egress":{"all":["216.198.0.0/18","52.27.183.82/32"],"specific":["216.198.0.0/18","54.88.153.44/32"]}}}
```

I would like to get only CIDRSs which appears **after** "egress":

```
["216.198.0.0/18","52.27.183.82/32","216.198.0.0/18","54.88.153.44/32"]
```

I have my pattern to find all CIDRs:

```
(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\/[0-9]{1,2}
```

And I'v tried, unsuccessfully,  using lookbehind:

1. `(?<=egress":{"all":\[)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\/[0-9]{1,2}`
2. `(?<=egress":{"all":\[).*?(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\/[0-9]{1,2}`
3. `(?<=egress":{"all":\[).*(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\/[0-9]{1,2}`

And few other options.

Thanks!

Comment: You can fix the JSON and parse it with `json`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, but I need to use regex here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest fixing the JSON keys by adding `":` where it is missing, and then use the `json` library to parse the JSON and get all your required values:

```py
import json
import re
s = '''{"ips":{"ingress":{"all["104.16.51.111/32","104.16.53.111/32"],"specific["104.16.51.111/32","104.16.53.111/32"]},"egress":{"all["216.198.0.0/18","52.27.183.82/32"],"specific":["216.198.0.0/18","54.88.153.44/32"]}}}'''
js = json.loads(re.sub(r'("\w+)(\[")', r'\1":\2', s))
all = js["ips"]["egress"]["all"]
all.extend(js["ips"]["egress"]["specific"])
print(all)
# => ['216.198.0.0/18', '52.27.183.82/32', '216.198.0.0/18', '54.88.153.44/32']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/F8iWBH).

The `("\w+)(\[")` regex matches and captures `"` and one or more word chars into Group 1 and then captures `["` into Group 2 and then the `\1":\2` replacement pattern puts back Group 1 value, appends `":` and then Group 2 values. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O7XPSM/1).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm aware of the option to use json, but I need to use regex in this case.

Comment: @ניבאילני No, you do not. You MUST NOT use regex to parse JSON. It is wrong from ALL angles. Unless you explain what you mean, this is the best solution you can have.

Comment: This is a general question, in this case it is a JSON, but it could be any other pattern such as xml, plain txt, html etc.

Comment: @ניבאילני The procedure must always be the same: 1) convert the string to proper JSON format, 2) parse with JSON. Everything else will be too fragile and won't work with any arbitrary JSON strings. Parsing JSON can and should always be done with proper tools, not regex - Wiktor Stribiżew.